# Prolog - simplifying two predicates into one

Tags: list, split, prolog, predicate, inverse

I have two prolog predicates that perform very similar functions, and I would like to make them into one to simplify things.
These are the predicates:

```
join(DELIM, [X|XS], RESULT) :-
    join(DELIM, XS, RXS),
    append([X, DELIM, RXS], RESULT).
join(DELIM, [END], END).

split(DELIM, [X|XS], RESULT) :-
    append([X, DELIM, RXS], RESULT),
    split(DELIM, XS, RXS).
split(DELIM, [END], END).
```

The first takes a delimiter and a list of lists, and joins them together using the delimiter. The other does the opposite, splitting one list into a list of other lists based on a delimiter. Even though their arguments are in the same places, if I try to interchange them, they will not work.
If at all, how can I make these two predicates into one?

Comment: They're not *functions* in Prolog. They're *predicates*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`append/2`](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=append%2f3) seems viable:

```
delim(D, Xs, [Ls|Ys]) :-
    append([Ls, D, Rs], Xs),
    delim(D, Rs, Ys).
delim(_, Xs, [Xs]).

?- delim([x],[1,x,2,3,x,4],R).
R = [[1], [2, 3], [4]] ;
...

?- delim([x],Xs,[[1], [2, 3], [4]]).
Xs = [1, x, 2, 3, x, 4] 
.
```

beware: could be not [universally terminating](https://www.w3.org/People/Massimo/papers/amast96.pdf) :-)